# How do I specify the "Navigation Page", i.e. the page I want my app to start with in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

In Windows Phone 8.0 I used to be able to specify Navigation Page in the file WMAppManifest.xml under Properties. This was the page that my app would navigate to first. However, in 8.1 this doesn't appear to be available.

How can I specify the start page for my app in Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of your App (*Silverlight*/*WinRT*):

- in *Silverlight* you specify the *Entry Point* in *package.appxmanifest* file (of course you can also redirect in app.xaml.cs)
- in *WinRT* (Store apps) - you will find in App.xaml.cs an *OnLaunched()* method and inside it the navigation is performed:

  ```
  if (rootFrame.Content == null)
      {
          // rootframe's content may also not be null so you should proabbly handle
          // also that situation
          rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
      }
  ```

In WP8.1 Store apps you should also handle other situations like when your app is *Activated*, *Sharing* (if you support it). Some help you may also find [at MSDN about Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464925.aspx).